# CSS works on Desktop, Strange on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this great script. It flips the page and reveals new items using a JS code on the backside of this text. But for some reason, on mobile, things go wrong. The h1 and h2 elements disappear...

The issue lies in this css, when I remove the `@keyframes` it goes away (but then I lose my background):

```
.background{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px}
.blue-purple{background-color:#2474c6;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2474c6, #165730);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#2474c6, #165730);-webkit-animation:fadeInOut 13s ease;-moz-animation:fadeInOut 13s ease;animation:fadeInOut 13s ease;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-iteration-count:infinite}
.green-blue{background-color:#165730;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #165730, #185a9d);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#165730, #185a9d);-webkit-animation:fadeOutIn 13s ease;-moz-animation:fadeOutIn 13s ease;animation:fadeOutIn 13s ease;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-iteration-count:infinite}

@-webkit-keyframes "fadeInOut"{0%{opacity:0;}50%{opacity:1;}100%{opacity:0;}}
@-moz-keyframes "fadeInOut"{0%{opacity:0;}50%{opacity:1;}100%{opacity:0;}}
@keyframes "fadeInOut"{0%{opacity:0;}50%{opacity:1;}100%{opacity:0;}}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeOutIn"{0%{opacity:1;}50%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}@-moz-keyframes "fadeOutIn"{0%{opacity:1;}50%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}
@keyframes "fadeOutIn"{0%{opacity:1;}50%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeIn"{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes "fadeIn"{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
@keyframes "fadeIn"{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}@-webkit-keyframes "fadeOut"{from{opacity:1;}to{opacity:0;}}
@-moz-keyframes "fadeOut"{from{opacity:1;}to{opacity:0;}}
@keyframes "fadeOut"{from{opacity:1;}to{opacity:0;}}
```

and some of the HTML:

```
<body>

    <!----><div class="background blue-purple"></div>
    <div class="background green-blue"></div> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="inner">
                <h1>text here</h1>
            </div>
                <span>sub text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
             <h2>Text</h2>
             <p>Further Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: give a screenshot @Jonathan Safa

Comment: Do you have the viewport meta tag in place => `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ?

Comment: Yes, but the error is with the @-webkit-keyframes... When I remove those, the issue goes away... but then I obviously lose my great background animations...

Comment: One workaround would be setting `display: block.` to your `<div>` where you're doing the animation

Comment: No, that didn't seem to work. It's like the animations are taking control over those `<div class="back">`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I just replaced it with a different background. I had a stupid code in there.